# Do i need to install all the drivers on my dell Windows 7 laptop?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, dell-inspiron

I have recently reinstalled windows 7 on my DELL inspiron n5010 laptop. Do i need to install all the drivers [listed on this page](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Pages/Drivers/inspiron-15-intel-n5010.html)

Comment: @Mohit - Only if you have a device that is not working

Comment: Dell is easy. Go to this link and enter your laptop's service tag found somewhere on a sticker attached to the laptop http://www.dell.com/support/my-support/us/en/19/product-support/servicetag

Answer (score 1):

Windows may have some generic drivers, but it's almost always best to update to the manufacturer's listed drivers. If you *really* don't want to, just update the ones that aren't recognized at all, but I do recommend you install all of them anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to make sure that you have your network card and your wifi working and just run windows 7 update.
The update might take a while but it will install all the essential drivers for your devices and the latest security patches.

Answer (score 1):

No **you don't need** install all the drivers and principally programs that already comes with a CD in new Laptops or Computers.

I would suggest to install all the drivers that appears as Driver Not Found in the `Device Manager`. When you have all the drivers in `Device Manager` installed, let Windows update them.